# Unwanted whitespace in -webkit-linear-gradient in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have the following styling for a div:

```
.so-post-content-quote {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0px, darkseagreen 0px), linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 30px, darkseagreen 20px), linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 0px, darkseagreen 0px), linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 30px, darkseagreen 0px);
  background-position: bottom left, top left, top right, bottom right;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 50px 20px 50px 20px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: white; 
}
```

And this is the HTML part:

```
<div class="so-post-content-quote">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
</div>
```

The result is:

[image]

How can I fix the vertical whitespace right at the center? This is the shape I wanted to create and I can do it but the whitespace looks annoying.

Comment: Fine in Chrome and FF

Comment: @dippas it works fine in Firefox but the screenshot above is from Chrome (and not only on my PC)

Comment: Have to tried to resize the browser window? Do you have the current version of the Chrome Browser?

Comment: @JiiB it sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. It's really odd. I have Chromium 62.0.3202.89.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a quck fix, if you change the the `background-size` to 51%:

css:

```
.so-post-content-quote-fix {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0px, darkseagreen 0px), linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 30px, darkseagreen 20px), linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 0px, darkseagreen 0px), linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 30px, darkseagreen 0px);
  background-position: bottom left, top left, top right, bottom right;
  background-size: 51% 51%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 50px 20px 50px 20px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: white; 
}
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/18875/

Comment: I only tested it in chrome 62. maybe you have to check the other browsers